# Synchronous removing values from array

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, asynchronous, synchronous

For a webinterface there is the possibility to delete certain properties. This properties are stored in an array and I will loop over these array and delete the selected ones.

Because I write the properties file after each remove it gets mashed up sometimes because of the asynchronisation I guess?

I select property A, B and C.

A will be removed, the file will be written without `A   ->   [B,C].`

Next in line `B will be removed`, but `C also started` and still has `B in his memory`.

B will be removed from the previous step and the file will be written, but afterwards C will be removed and the file will be written with B back in it.

*Result -> Remaning array with B still in it.*

```
deleteSelected() {
   let count = 0;
   for (const propertyId of this.selectedProperties) {
     this.metadataPropertyService.deleteProperty(this.packageName, propertyId).then(
       result => {
         count++;
         if (count === this.selectedProperties.length) {
           this.ngOnChanges();
         }
       });
   }
 }`
```

```
public IData deleteProperty(IData pipeline){
       PropertyInput propertyInput = IDataToObjectParser.getDeletePropertyInput(pipeline);
       List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<>(getProperties(propertyInput.getPackageName()));
       Property property = getProperty(properties, propertyInput.getId());
       if(properties.remove(property)){
           return writeProperties(FileUtils.getFile(propertyInput.getPackageName(), configurations), properties);
       }
       Error error = new Error("MTD-WR-01", "TECHNICAL","Cannot remove property with id " + propertyInput.getId());
       return ObjectToIDataParser.getStatus(new Status(State.ERROR, error));
   }
```

I expected that with `.then()` the code will be runned synchronous and the deleteProperty will run it one by one. Anyone got an **alternative?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `async/await` approach:

```
async function deleteSelected() {
    for (const propertyId of this.selectedProperties) {
        await this.metadataPropertyService.deleteProperty(this.packageName, propertyId)
    }
    this.ngOnChanges();
}
```

You dont need the `count` variable anymore because you are running the delete operations synchronously, so when the `for` loop ends you have already deleted all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` replacing the `.then()`

```
async deleteSelected() {
       let count = 0;
       for (const propertyId of this.selectedProperties) {
        await result =  this.metadataPropertyService.deleteProperty(this.packageName, propertyId);
           count++;
           if (count === this.selectedProperties.length) {
               this.ngOnChanges();
             }
       }
     }
```